# Ubuntu running slowly after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, upgrade, intel-graphics

I recently updated my system from 11.04 to 12.04.
UI is too slow.
System specs:
Acer aspire 4715z, 1gb ram, dual-core, mobile intel grahics

Reading other links suggest to switch back to Gnome/unity 2D, but Unity was working fine in 11.04.
Does any other upgrade is required?

Comment: Install fresh ubuntu 12.04 instead of upgrade

Comment: I installed freshly from usb..

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Unity 2D, it will make all the difference.